# Magenta noise on images?

Tags: troubleshooting, canon-5d-mark-iii

Does anyone know why I'm getting magenta noise on my images.  It's very inconsistent when it happens, and I'm having a hard time figuring out what's causing it. [image]

I'm seeing the 'noise' predominantly in the circled areas below...

[image]

Comment: **Nice photo!** On my calibrated, 97%sRGB monitor, I cannot see "magenta noise" in this picture. I can see some areas that are noisy and magenta by natura, and I can see some areas that are highlighted magenta. It does look a bit magenta-ish in total to me. Could you maybe draw an arrow or circle to the areas so I can see it more easily?

Comment: Are you talking about a magenta color cast or noise?  A color cast likely indicates a white balance problem.  Also, changing camera, subject, and lighting placement can make the amount of magenta vary from image to image.  Noise would look like random specks.  It is expected to be "inconsistent" because it is random.

Comment: @xiota well....some (most?) cameras have a dominant purplish--magentaish noise in boosted dark areas. while noise should be random, there is nothing that forbids it to have something dominant about it. compare with white or pink noise in acoustics.

Comment: I can see it, especially obvious on the backdrop. It's not noise as I define it, more like quantization effects from compression. Is this from a RAW file or JPG?

Comment: I also see magenta in the backdrop.  It looks like a color cast to me, combined with compression artifacts.

Comment: @Julie S What kind of lighting were you using? What shutter speed, aperture, and ISO did you use? Did you save raw files or straight to jpeg in-camera? What postprocessing, if any, was applied using what application?

Comment: To clarify, I'm not new to studio portrait photography (10 years in) with studio lighting, and I'm WELL trained in photography, lighting, etc. This problem is something VERY new, and random.  @BobT, thanks! I call it noise, I didn't know what else to call it?  Shoot in raw, download to LR in raw. I see it on raw image, before editing, though. I process first in LR, and finish in PS, save in jpeg or tiff, after saving edits in LR. I don't know what changed that this is now happening? And, it's random. Could it be a memory card problem?  I have several memory cards.  Some are big storage cards.

Comment: Thanks ALL for your input!!  I really appreciate the feedback!!

Comment: I added where I think the noise we are talking about is - please let us know if I got it right - we can always change it if not. [it's a bit vague & looks different at different zoom factors]

Comment: Can't be the memory card (or any storage media). If random bits are changed in a picture, you don't see noise, you see a broken picture. Did you update LR recently? Is still LR using the very same settings ?

Comment: One way to test would be to use a different RAW converter just for verification. E.g. Canon's Digital Photo Professional (free) or a freeware like Darktable, DigiKam, RawTherapee,... If the same noise is there on the same spots, then its likely your camera.

Comment: @Tetsujim yes that's some of it anyway. There's more on this image.

Comment: I have been using LR CC classic.  But I do on all of my images, and it doesn't happen every time.  And, I use two different computers sometimes.  Happens on both.  That's why I thought memory card.  Now I'm thinking it's my camera.  Must call Canon tomorrow.

Comment: i see green bands directly beside the magenta ones. might be some form of colour noise from the sensor.

Answer (score 1):

I also see yellow noise along with the magenta.

Possibilities.

1)  Possibly processing artifacts from in camera or in post.  Are you shooting RAW or jpeg?  Is it happening in the original image or in post processing?

2)  Reflections from colored objects in the room or light coming though a window or relecting off glass and creating a prism effect.

3)  Are you down converting your color bit depth or converting to a substandard profile?

4)  Do you have the saturation cranked up?  It looks oversaturated, especially on the skin.  There is noticeable clipping.

5) Have you switched your lights to see if it's a failing bulb?  It could be an old bulb.

6)  Are you using a filter?  It may be dirty or smeared.

My guess is saturation/clipping based on limited info and what I see in the pic.

Answer (score 0):

First of all. Make some more tests.

Take a photo of a pure white surface, a piece of new paper, take it out of focus and take a look. Try to isolate some other factors, like the time you are using the camera (this can heat the sensor) or room temperature.

There is a chance something is happening to your sensor, probably some overheating.

(I have a similar problem with a video camera. I'll make some tests too)

(Offtopic. Probably you are pushing too much magenta into the processing, therefore exaggerating a bit a magenta cast)